# How can I tell if a program on a remote Windows computer is running?

Tags: java, windows, remote-access

I would like to write/run a program on a Win10 laptop that would tell me if a set of programs is running one or more other Windows computers to which I have login access.  Those programs were written in Java/Scala and are run as Services on the remote computer(s).  The program I would write/run from a Win10 laptop would likely be written in Scala.  I want to create a web page with a table / dashboard that tells me which programs are running, and maybe take a peek at recent log entries.

Comment: Without more info, I can imagine two possible strategies. One using Windows .NET or DCOM with full access to Windows system primitives - but hard to write in Java-Scala, one using JMS or JMX and collaborating Java applications. IMHO an element of decision is whether the Java service are/can be instrumented...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks, I'm just trying to figure out if this is even possible, so you've given me some leads to pursue.